# How to rename the file names in a folder with new names of text file line by line in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import csv
import os

with open('newnames.csv') as cs:
     reader = csv.reader(cs)
     for row in reader:
         oldname = row[0]
         newname = row[1]
         os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

This is my example code to read a new names from an "csv" and rename it in the specified file name in old name.

For example i have a csv file as in image:

[![Sample CSV file][1]][1]

But i have a requirement to read a new names from an text file like oldname,newname in a text file as line by line and rename it into the specified files.can you please guide me for this.

**New Code:**

```
import os
with open('new.txt')as f:
     line= f.readlines()
     parts = line.split(",")
     txt = os.rename(parts[0].strip(), parts[1].strip())
```

**Example Text File:**

```
shadow,OARI

coupler,ddpl

trunt,dream

field,land
```

**New:**

```
import os

with open('new.txt') as names:
     for line in names:
         parts = line.strip().split(",")
         oldname = parts[0]
         newname = parts[1]
         os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

Comment: At what point did you stuck? This one should work after removing reader line. Are your files-to-be-renamed in the same folder with your .py file?

Comment: yes.In the same folder only it should be rename.

Comment: Can you provide a sample from your txt file by editing your question?

Comment: updated my example code and text file above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are reading whole file and splitting all of them into a one list. Instead of that, try to read line-by-line and split each of them by iterating over file.

```
import os

with open('your_txt_file_name.txt') as names:
     for line in names:
         if line.strip(): #this strip makes you skip empty lines
             parts = line.split(",")
             oldname = parts[0] #you can use strip here depending on your txt
             newname = parts[1] #you can use strip here depending on your txt
             os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

Comment: But here "row" not defined.Then how it will run.

Comment: I have finished as above code(new).that is also working fine

Comment: That also works but if you don't check if line is empty or not, you will get an IndexError when you have an empty line.

Comment: Ok.Thank you so much for your support.